Como redireccionar a un usuario de un dominio a otro
les cuento mi problema. Estoy creando una pagina para un restaurante y he estado teniendo problemas con la redireccion de un dominio a otro.
Este restaurante, antiguamente tenia un sitio web ya publicado bajo el dominio de laguacarena.com. Sin embargo, era una pagina que nunca fue finalizada y faltaban muchas cosas por hacer
Por ello, yo hice un sitio web nuevo para este restaurante y lo aloje en Firebase, el dominio que me dio fue asadoslagu.web.app
Luego de que termine el sitio web, transferi el dominio laguacarena.com a el nuevo sitio web que yo hice, lo cual funciono perfectamente, cuando los usuarios acceden a laguacarena.com, pueden ver el nuevo sitio web y no el antiguo.
Ahora el problema esta en que me gustaria que los usuarios que visiten el sitio web a traves del dominio asadoslagu.web.app, sean redireccionados inmediatamente a laguacarena.com
Intente colocando la redireccion en el archivo firebase.json, pero al hacerlo, el sitio web no funciona porque me da un mensaje que dice "laguacarena.com redirected you too many times"
apreciaria mucho si me pudieran ayudar con esto ya que llevo dias intentando y no logro dar con el problema, muchas gracias!!
archivo Firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "https://laguacarena.com/",
        "type": 301
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  }
}

